# App Engine stackdriver logging to Global log instead of service log

Tags: django, google-app-engine, logging, stackdriver

I'm trying to set up logging for a django app hosted as an App Engine service on GAE.

I have set up the logging succesfully, except that the logging is showing up in the global log for that entire project instead of the log for that service. I would like for the logs to show up only in the specific service logs

this is my django logging config:

```
from google.cloud import logging as google_cloud_logging


log_client = google_cloud_logging.Client()
log_client.setup_logging()

LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'stackdriver_logging': {
            'class': 'google.cloud.logging.handlers.CloudLoggingHandler',
            'client': log_client
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        '': {
            'handlers': ['stackdriver_logging'],
            'level': 'INFO',
        }
    },
}
```

And I am able to succesfully log to the Global project log by calling like this:

```
def fetch_orders(request):
    logger.error('test error')
    logger.critical('test critical')
    logger.warning('test warning')
    logger.info('test info')
    return redirect('dashboard')
```

I'm wanting to figure out if I can configure the logger to always use the log for the service that it's running in.

EDIT:

I tried the suggestion below, however now it is returning the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/logging/handlers/transports/background_thread.py", line 122, in _safely_commit_batch
    batch.commit()
  File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/logging/logger.py", line 381, in commit
    entries = [entry.to_api_repr() for entry in self.entries]
  File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/logging/logger.py", line 381, in <listcomp>
    entries = [entry.to_api_repr() for entry in self.entries]
  File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/logging/entries.py", line 318, in to_api_repr
    info = super(StructEntry, self).to_api_repr()
  File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/logging/entries.py", line 241, in to_api_repr
    info["resource"] = self.resource._to_dict()
AttributeError: 'ConvertingDict' object has no attribute '_to_dict'
```

I can over-ride this in the package source code to make it work, however the GAE environment requires that I use the package as supplied by google for the cloud logging. Is there any way to go from here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my understanding, it should be possible to accomplish what you want using the `resource` option of [CloudLoggingHandler](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/blob/master/logging/google/cloud/logging/handlers/handlers.py). In the Stackdriver Logging (and Stackdriver Monitoring) API, each object (log line, time-series point) is associated with a "resource" (some thing that exists in a project, that can be provisioned, and can be the source of logs or time-series or the thing that the logs or time-series are being written about). When the `resource` option is omitted, the `CloudLoggingHandler` defaults to `global` as you have observed.

There are a number of [monitored resource types](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/api/v2/resource-list#resource-types), including `gae_app`, which can be used to represent a specific version of a particular service that is deployed on GAE. Based on your code, this would look something like:

```
from google.cloud.logging import resource


def get_monitored_resource():
  project_id = get_project_id()
  gae_service = get_gae_service()
  gae_service_version = get_gae_service_version()
  resource_type = 'gae_app'
  resource_labels = {
    'project_id': project_id,
    'module_id': gae_service,
    'version_id': gae_service_version
  }
  return resource.Resource(resource_type, resource_labels)


GAE_APP_RESOURCE = get_monitored_resource() 
LOGGING = {
    # ...
    'handlers': {
        'stackdriver_logging': {
            'class': 'google.cloud.logging.handlers.CloudLoggingHandler',
            'client': log_client,
            'resource': GAE_APP_RESOURCE,
        },
    },
    # ...
}
```

In the code above, the functions `get_project_id`, `get_gae_service`, and `get_gae_service_version` can be implemented in terms of the environment variables `GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT`, `GAE_SERVICE`, and `GAE_VERSION` in the Python flexible environment as documented by [The Flexible Python Runtime](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/runtime) as in:

```
def get_project_id():
  return os.getenv('GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT')
```

Comment: New problem, would you mind taking a look at the error above?

Comment: It looks like you are using the wrong definition for resource; see the class here: https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/blob/master/logging/google/cloud/logging/resource.py Note that this class has the method '_to_dict()', which the error says it does not. It sounds like perhaps you passed in some other object as the resource?

Comment: It looks like it's something to do with Django specifically. ConvertingDict / ConvertingTuple is something that I discovered is part of Django. I'm not sure why, but it takes the Resource object and tries to treat it as one of those objects. The setup was correct, but Django just wants to override it. I could modify the library directly, but GAE requires use of the google-cloud-logging package, so that isn't an option either. I think I'll just live with it, and set up a custom filter in the global log for now

Comment: I think you're right. Before giving up, try doing what you did with the 'stackdriver_logging' entry; instead of passing in a Resource object, try passing in a dict, where you have a 'class' entry that gives the fully-qualified name of the 'Resource' class; perhaps that will get auto-converted to the Resource object?

Comment: Alternatively: you could try to add the logging handler directly, rather than attempting to do so via the special 'LOGGING' configuration dict (e.g. by retrieving a logger and then calling the 'addHandler' method explicitly to register the handler).